# Swift TextFieldEffects not working--error with #selector?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm working on an IOS app, and I used cocoapods to download the TextFieldsEffects. However, right away my build fails, because I get an error on the line `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldDidEndEditing), name: UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: self)`

This is in the TextFieldEffects.swift file, and the error message is "Expected expression in list of expressions" and it prompts me to put a comma before the '#', but that doesn't fix it either. It doesn't like the '#' sign, and I'm guessing it's because that sign was deprecated in Swift 2.0 but I'm not sure what it does (I know it's not the regular use to silence an external parameter) so I don't know how to fix it. Anyone know how to make this work? I just want to use the TextFieldEffects so my UI looks nice, but I can't even get it to run. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you upgraded Xcode to 7.3?

Comment: [Swift 2.2 introduced new selector syntax](https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-selector-syntax-sugar-81c8a8b10df3#.en1ht4pod). Try updating Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you haven't upgraded to Xcode 7.3. In this case, you have two options:

1) Update to Xcode 7.3 (Recommended)

2) Use an older version of textFieldEffects in your Podfile